# Update for Windows XP (KB927891)

Tags: windows-xp

I am trying to re-install Windows XP SP3 (don't ask), and I am following the instructions from:

- https://superuser.com/a/696262/106444

However I am stuck on item (3):

- Update for Windows XP (KB927891)

The link:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927891/you-receive-an-access-violation-error-and-the-system-may-appear-to-bec

is working fine, however if I go down to the XP link, this lead to:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7a81b0cd-a0b9-497e-8a89-404327772e5a

Which is today:

```
$ HEAD "http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7a81b0cd-a0b9-497e-8a89-404327772e5a"
503 Service Unavailable
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:03:47 GMT
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:03:47 GMT
Client-Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:03:47 GMT
Client-Peer: 23.40.97.126:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Mime-Version: 1.0
TLS_version: UNKNOWN
X-Reference-Error: 119.65aacd17.1580303027.3321a58
X-RTag: StMus
```

Other reference:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-update-kb927891-for-windows-xp-32-bit-is/bc66c942-dcfa-48f7-908c-ca45cc5d64bc

Where can I find KB927891 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft's catalog update site is the best place to search and find updates to download, the safest also.

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB927891